# Composition of Partial Isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a linear operator in $H$, a Hilbert space.
An operator $T \in L(H)$ is said to be a *partial isometry* if the restriction of $T$ to $ker(T)^{\perp}$ is an isometry. I would like to prove that given a partial isometry $T$, then $T^{2}$ is a partial isometry if and only if $(T^{*}TTT^{*})$=$(TT^{*}T^{*}T)$. All I could do so far was to prove the *classic* result : $T=TT^{*}T$ iff $T$ is a partial isometry iff $T^{*}=T^{*}TT^{*}$, that might be useful.
Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove this using the following observation: Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. Then $T$ is a partial isometry if and only if the spectrum of $T^{\ast} T$ consists only of $\{0,1\}$. Furthermore, let $A$ be a bounded, self-adjoint operator. Then $\sigma(A) \subset \{0,1\}$ if and only if $A = A^2$; this follows from the spectral theorem.

So our general strategy to prove that $T$ is an isometry should be to prove the equivalent relation $T^{\ast} T = (T^{\ast} T)^2$. If you apply this directly, you get your "classic" result $T = TT^{\ast} T$. So all that remains for you to prove the partial isometry condition for $T^2$ is to check all this instead with $T^* T^* TT = (T^*T^* TT)^2$.

Comment: The algebraic characterization should be $A=A^2$ (a projection), not $A=A^3$.

Comment: Oh, of course, why was I so confused!?

Comment: Thanks Christopher !